General method for finding the remainder in an asymptotic series
I enrolled in grad school after getting my electrical engineering B.S. 5 years ago :| My math is rusty. My professor has this example for a series solution to the integral below.
$$
\int_{x}^{\infty }\frac{e^{-t}}{t}dt = \frac{e^{-x}}{x}\left[1-\frac{1!}{x}+\frac{2!}{x^{2}}-\cdots+ (-1)^{n}\frac{n!}{x^{n}}\right] + (-1)^{n+1}(n+1)!\int_{x}^{\infty }\frac{e^{-t}}{t^{n+2}}dt
$$
where the remainder is ...
$$
R_{n} = (-1)^{n+1}(n+1)!\int_{x}^{\infty }\frac{e^{-t}}{t^{n+2}}dt
$$
I can solve the series with using integration by parts and finding the pattern. I can't figure out why the remainder term looks the way it does. I found other examples online and they usually leave the remainder in big O notation or I too can not figure out how the $R_n(x)$ term is solved (found?).
Is there a generalized method or pattern I'm missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Maybe gentle help if possible since I'm relearning my math.

You can obtain the expression by repeatedly integrating by parts, which will provide the explicit form for the remainder. Alternatively, by setting $t = x + s$,
$$
\int_x^{+\infty} \frac{{\rm e}^{-t}}{t} \, {\rm d}t = {\rm e}^{-x} \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{{\rm e}^{-s}}{x + s} \, {\rm d}s = \frac{{\rm e}^{-x}}{x} \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{{\rm e}^{-s}}{1 + s/x} \, {\rm d}s.
$$
Now, substituting the identity (for $n \ge 0$)
$$
\frac{1}{1 + s/x} = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k s^k \frac{1}{x^k} + (-1)^{n+1} \frac{s^{n+1}}{1 + s/x} \frac{1}{x^{n+1}},
$$
and integrating term by term, we obtain
$$
\int_x^{+\infty} \frac{{\rm e}^{-t}}{t} \, {\rm d}t = \frac{{\rm e}^{-x}}{x} \left( \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \frac{k!}{x^k} + (-1)^{n+1} \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{s^{n+1} {\rm e}^{-s}}{1 + s/x} \, {\rm d}s \frac{1}{x^{n+1}} \right).
$$
This method yields a different expression for the remainder. Note that letting $n \to +\infty$ is not possible, as the infinite series would not converge for any $x$.
In general, obtaining explicit expressions for remainder terms in asymptotic expansions is difficult. For remainder terms in asymptotic expansions arising from the method of steepest descent applied to integrals of the form
$$
\int_\mathscr{C} {\rm e}^{-x f(t)} g(t) \, {\rm d}t, \quad x \to \infty,
$$
refer to this paper. F. W. J. Olver's excellent book Asymptotics and Special Functions also provides methods for obtaining explicit error bounds for asymptotic expansions.
